# Laravel 7 login does not work when logging in first time but later is working

Tags: authentication, laravel-7

I am using *laravel 7.0 default authentication* and the login does not work when logging in first time. No errors are show. It just takes forever in processing the request and when I cancel the ongoing request and try again, it logs in. I am using my localhost to serve the app.
Any suggestions why its doing this

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=legal_action
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

Comment: have you installed login ui using `composer require laravel/ui`? Check https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-routing

Comment: yes sir same command also found this while searching for the problem https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32102

Comment: Is your laravel app connected to a database? Check your .env file for the `SESSION_DRIVER`, if possible update your question with .env file obscuring any security credentials.

Comment: sir i have updated my question with .env file.

Comment: Everything in your .env file looks normal. Can I suggest installing larave debugbar and just see if you see any latency in the requests etc. Also are you using local database or is it in a cloud/external server?

Comment: I am using my local database.i will use debugger but i have not changed anything in the default laravel login system.So maybe its a problem with laravel maybe as some other users are also facing it.

Comment: And Sir this problem only occurs in chrome the app is working fine on other browsers.So what do you suggest i should i have also tried custom login but same result??

Comment: It is difficult to judge what the issue could be with limited access to your application and system. Since it is browser specific, is it possible for you to disable any extensions e.g. adblockers and check as well (maybe one of them is blocking something). Alternatively reinstall your browser and check. If there are some logs e.g. server logs you would have to share those. Also check your console for any requests being sent and see if there are any errors. Also if you can share your code somewhere it would be good.